# How to export and use classes_ from LabelEncoder() in different applications?

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, pickle, flask-wtforms

During the pre-processing steps of my project I'm using `LabelEncoder()` a lot to convert things likes states (e.g. 'California') to nice values to train my models with. I'm doing the bulk of my development in **jupyter notebooks**, and eventually I pickle my model to use in a separate application behind a purpose-written API and web app. The models are complex and training and pre-processing takes a couple of hours.

I want to however use the same `classes_` I encoded and trained the model with, but then somewhere inside my API. It isn't sensible to train the model again when I boot up the server just to have access to the `classes_`.

What's more is that I want to actually offer the `classes_` as options in the forms I show in my little web app. I could simply store these with pickle or as plain json then read them in on the API, and use these to populate the options in my forms, but there should be something less crude and I think it might be a performance bottleneck or a potential resource hog. What's a good way to do this?

tl;dr:

- I want to pickle the `classes_` I get from `LabelEncoder()` inside my jupyter notebook to process things I receive on an API. Is this a good/ fast way to do this?
- I also want to pickle the `classes_` I get from `LabelEncoder()` to be used for generating forms (on a separate app) where these need to be shown as options. They will be consumed by a python (flask) application.

Comment: Why not pickle the entire `LabelEncoder` object and use the `transform` method?

Comment: I had not thought of that! That sounds like a perfect solution to my problem.